# Zip file does not open from internet explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpresponse

I have tried two methods to open a zip file from internet explorer, but none works.

Method 1

```
<li>
    <a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/HelpDocs/IMs_Guide.zip")%>">IM User Guide</a>
</li>
```

With this method, I can see the "Open" dialog box. If I click on "Open", it may be trying to open it. But the file is not opened.

Method 2

```
<li>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDownloadUserGuide" Text="IM User Guide" runat="server" Visible="true" OnClick="btnDownloadUserGuide_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnUserGuide" runat="server" Value="~/HelpDocs/IMs_Guide.zip" /></li>
```

Code behind (Method 2)

```
protected void btnDownloadUserGuide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!hdnUserGuide.Value.Trim().Equals(""))
    {
        //string strFileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() + "\\HelpDocs\\IMs_Guide.zip";
        string FilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("\\HelpDocs\\IMs_Guide.zip");

        string strFileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() + "\\HelpDocs\\IMs_Guide_to_New_Q-Track.zip";
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "IMs_Guide.zip");
        Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        Response.ContentType = "Application/x-zip-compressed";

        Response.WriteFile(FilePath);
        //Response.End();
        Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }
}
```

With this method, it may be trying to open it, but no "Open" dialog box is seen. File is not opened.

If attempt is made to save it instead of opening the file, that works.
The same issue is observed if the file type is changed to doc or pdf.

The same code (both methods) work in Chrome and Mozilla browsers.

Comment: Have you tried this on any other browsers? does it just download it and not open? With IE you need to associate an action for file types

Comment: Download the link and open whatever gets saved in a text editor, see what you get.

Comment: Yes. Works well in Chrome and Mozilla.

Comment: @MarcB : when you say "download", do you mean to click on "Save" and open the downloaded file in text editor? When I try that, I get garbled text (since the downloaded file is zip file).

Comment: yes,exactly. but you also need to look for anything that'd cause the zip to appear corrupted, e.g. stray html, server error messages, etc...

Comment: Are you actually using IE and not Edge? Edge allows the use of [the `download` attribute on an anchor tag](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#downloading-resources), but not IE (see http://caniuse.com/#feat=download).